# How to limit the number of rows displayed for Datatables but still keeping the total number of Data returned?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a .NET web app where I will be displaying records retrieving from an SQL database

As I try to make the connection to the Datatabase, I found an issue that the records could not be displayed in the UI because out of memory error occurred as too many records (nearly 20000) would be retrieved from database. How can I make adjustment to the code that only top 100 records will be showed on the page, and the other records can be searched from database by entering keyword in the Search box at top-right corner of the Datatables

Thank you!

Comment: This is the problem which [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) is designed to solve. There are lots of related questions and answers already on Stack Overflow (as well as the official documentation, and [examples](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/index.html)).

Comment: An alternative solution that I have used is to have an input with `keyup` event handler that sends an Ajax request to your server, and you populate the DataTable with the response. You could have a default set if you want to show some data on page load.